# Python retrieve specific rows from a csv file

Tags: python, list, csv

I'm trying to retrieve specific rows from my csv file and than to create a new csv file form them. The rows I'm retrieving must contain the same value present into a list.

```
myList=[HELLO, WORLD, DAD]

csv_file=      doc_01 | doc_02 | doc_03 | doc_04 |
         HELLO| 0,002 | 0,8    | 00,5   | 0,003  |
         WORLD| 0,1   | 00,9   | 1,2    | 2,1    |
         MOM  | 00,3  | 00,7   | 0,22   | 0,55   |
```

My intention is to iterate over the list and, if the value in the list is in the first column of the csv I want to take all the corrisponding row.

The result should be like:

```
new_csv=       doc_01 | doc_02 | doc_03 | doc_04 |
         HELLO| 0,002 | 0,8    | 00,5   | 0,003  |
         WORLD| 0,1   | 00,9   | 1,2    | 2,1    |
```

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Did you try anything? If so lets discuss it.

Comment: You question is not clear.

Comment: You can just read the csv - using e.g. `pandas` - into a dataframe and then easily select the required rows.

Comment: I have tryied this:                                                                                                        with open('totale.csv', 'rb') as infile:                                                                                           csv_reader = csv.reader(infile)
       for row in csv_reader:
        if row[0] in lista_diff :
            print (row)

Comment: edit your question with what you have tried. Also that doesn't look like a standard CSV format with the pipes in.

Comment: Follow @Cleb. You want to read into pandas and then filter afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the delimiter='|' when you read the data

```
import pandas as pd
import csv

df= pd.read_csv('C:\Users\shmathew\Desktop\Sample\sample.txt',sep='|')
myList=['HELLO', 'WORLD', 'DAD']
print df[df['doc_01'].isin(myList)]
```

or

```
infile=open('C:\Users\shmathew\Desktop\Sample\sample.txt', 'rb') 
csv_reader = csv.reader(infile,delimiter='|') 
for row in csv_reader: 
    if row[0] in myList :
        print (row)
```

creates the same output

```
    doc_01 doc_02 doc_03 doc_04 doc_05
    0  HELLO  0,002    0,8   00,5  0,003
    1  WORLD    0,1   00,9    1,2    2,1
```